# MultiTouch Scaling for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, scaling, multi-touch

I'm working on an app that will take four touches, scale them appropriately, and then send those values to control an embedded synthesizer.

What I have so far is:

```
//Assign seperate touches to scaling values
        _firstTouch=[[OneTouch alloc] initWithFrame:frame1
                                       scalingValue:PITCH_SCALING 
                                          withColor:[UIColor redColor]
                                           delegate:self
                     uniqueID:1];
        _secondTouch=[[OneTouch alloc] initWithFrame:frame2
                                        scalingValue:OFFSET_SCALING
                                           withColor:[UIColor blackColor]
                                            delegate:self
                      uniqueID:2];
        _thirdTouch=[[OneTouch alloc] initWithFrame:frame3
                                       scalingValue:DENSITY_SCALING
                                          withColor:[UIColor cyanColor]
                                           delegate:self
                     uniqueID:3];
        _fourthTouch=[[OneTouch alloc] initWithFrame:frame4
                                        scalingValue:DURATION_SCALING
                                           withColor:[UIColor orangeColor]
                                            delegate:self
                      uniqueID:4];
```

The "scaling" values are macros I set up in the corresponding .h file. They are:

```
#define PITCH_SCALING 1000.0
#define OFFSET_SCALING 20000.0
#define DENSITY_SCALING 100.0
#define DURATION_SCALING 1.0
```

What I can't figure out how to do is program each touch to go between the maximum (scaled) value and a minimum value (for example, pitch would scale between 100 and 1000).

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: I am not completely sure what you mean by scaling, and what your input and output is. But I think what you mean is that your input value is ranged `input` = [0, 1), and you want to map it to a different range (i.e. `min` = 100 and `max`=1000). Such a linear mapping is given as: `min` + (`max` -`min`) * `input`.

Comment: I would be wary of the number of users that have multitasking gestures enabled.  If they are enabled, iOS will steal 4 and 5 finger touches from your application.

Comment: @MikeS, That is an excellent point. Luckily for this code though, I'm only using it for my research project on an iPad with multi-tasking gestures disabled, and am not going to be trying to release it on the App Store.